# How to pass JSON to SwaggerUIBundle?

Tags: reactjs, swagger, swagger-ui

Is there a way to pass OpenAPI JSON contents directly to Swagger UI's `SwaggerUIBundle` instead of passing an URL?

I need to use Swagger UI in a React 16 app, but [`swagger-ui`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui) doesn't support React 16 so I'm using `SwaggerUIBundle` instead. Does anyone know how to use `swagger-ui` in React version 16+ or pass JSON into SwaggerUIBundle?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. It's best to have one issue per question to make things easier for future visitors. You have two questions here: 1) how to provide the spec as JSON; 2) How to use Swagger UI in React 16. Consider asking the React question as a [separate question](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 7):

To pass the spec as JSON, use the [`spec`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-spec) parameter:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  // BEGIN SPEC
  spec: {
    swagger: '2.0',
    info: {
      title: "test",
      version: '1.0.0'
    },
    paths: {
      '/foo': {
        get: {
          responses: {
            '200': {
              description: 'OK'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // END SPEC

  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  ...
```

> Please anyone know either how to use swagger-ui in react version 16+

Use [`swagger-ui-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react).

Comment: thx, it do works! but how to import swagger-ui.css, swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js and swagger-ui-bundle.js locally?

Comment: @lin I see you've asked a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851212/how-to-replace-swagger-ui-css-swagger-ui-standalone-preset-js-and-swagger-ui-bu) about imports. Hopefully someone will answer there.